# TypeError: L.heatLayer is not a function というエラーが、ライブラリのメソッドを呼んだ際に出る

Tags: javascript

ヒートマップで可視化しようとして、`Leaflet`と[`Leaflet.heat`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat) を利用しています。

コードを書いて、htmlファイルを開いてみたところ、初期のマップの表示はできてますが、ファイルを読み込んで、ヒートマップを描画するところでコンソールに

> TypeError: L.heatLayer is not a function
>   reader.onload()

と出て描画に失敗します。
`L.heatLayer`は`Leaflet.heat`のヒートマップのレイヤを呼び出すときに記述するものです。

以下、呼び出し部分です。よろしくお願いします。

```
var heatmap = L.heatLayer(data_array,{
    radius: range,
    blur: 10,
    maxZoom: 18,
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TypeError: L.heatLayer is not a function

というのは、`L.heatLayer`を呼び出しているけれど、これは関数ではないよ、という意味です。
参考: [TypeError: "x" is not a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function)

こういう時は、関数でないなら何なのか、をまず調べます。
`L.heatLayer` を呼び出す直前でログを出させます。

```
console.log("L.heatLayer: ", L.heatLayer);
```

このログを見ればだいたい解決すると思います。
`undefined` である事が多いですね。タイプミスなどが原因です。

質問のケースですと、Leaflet.heat というライブラリを読み込めていない可能性もあります。
その場合は、

- `<script src="leaflet-heat.js"></script>` を正しい位置に記述しているか
- `leaflet-heat.js` をサーバの正しい位置に配置しているか

あたりを確認する事になります。

Comment: 最初にログを見たところundefinedになっており、ソースを見直して
head内にleaflet.jsを記述し、bodyの<div id="map"></div>のすぐ下に <script src="http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.heat/dist/leaflet-heat.js"></script>
と記述して試してみたところ、コンソールには
L.heatLayer:  function L.heatLayer()index2.html:105:13
TypeError: t.addLayer is not a function
L.HeatLayer<.addTo()
leaflet-heat.js:11
reader.onload()
という風に変わりました。t.addLayerとはleaflet-heat.js内に登場するものですね・・・。

Comment: この質問の問題は解決しましたか？ していない場合は、問題が再現出来る最小限のコードを、質問を編集して記載して下さい。（最小限といっても、問題が再現出来なくなっては駄目です。コードの削り方が分からない場合は全て記載して下さい。）入力するファイルも最小限の物を記載して下さい。また、デバッグ中に使用するJavaScriptのライブラリは本番用の圧縮された物では無く、ソースが読めるようになっている物が用意されていますので、そちらを使用するとよいです。この質問とは別の問題が発生したという事でしたら、別の質問として投稿なさるのがよいです。

Comment: この質問の問題は解決しました。しかし、また別のエラー文が出てしまったので、また質問を投稿しなおすことにします。
丁寧な回答やアドバイスありがとうございました。

Comment: 多分ちょっとした事だと思うので頑張って下さい。質問は何度でも編集出来るので、途中で追加情報などがある時は、どんどん編集するとよいです。編集すると、他の方の目にも触れます。コメントだとコメント対象の投稿主しか、あまり見ないですね。