# TypeError: jquery_1.default(...).bootpag is not a function で落ちてしまいます．

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

[このJQueryは何をやっているんでしょう？？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/75296/%E3%81%93%E3%81%AEjquery%E3%81%AF%E4%BD%95%E3%82%92%E3%82%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86) の続きです．

検索を行って結果を表示、検索結果の下にbootpag（https://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/）を使用して、検索結果のページナビゲーションを表示しようとしています．

### bootpagのインストール

npm install --save bootpag

でプロジェクトにインストールしました．

### コードはTypeScriptで以下のように書いてあります．

```js
        if (totalPageNumber > 1) {
            // Add pagination widget
            $('#wh-search-pagination').bootpag({
                total: totalPageNumber, // total pages
                page: pageToShow,       // default page
                maxVisible: 10,         // visible pagination
                leaps: false,           // next/prev leaps through maxVisible
                next: localization.getLocalization("next.page"),
                prev: localization.getLocalization("prev.page")
            }).on("page", function(event:JQuery.Event, num:number){
                util.debug("Display page with number: ", Object(num));

                // Replace or add the page query
                let oldPage:string|undefined = util.getParameter("page");
                let oldQuery:string = window.location.search;
                let oldHref:string = window.location.href;
                let oldLocation:string = oldHref.substr(0, oldHref.indexOf(oldQuery));

                let newQuery:string = "";
                if (oldPage == undefined || oldPage == "") {
                    newQuery = oldQuery + "&page=" + String(num);
                } else {
                    let re:RegExp = new RegExp("(\\?|&)page\=" + oldPage);
                    newQuery = oldQuery.replace(re, "$1page="+String(num));
                }

                window.history.pushState("searchPage" + String(num), document.title, oldLocation + newQuery);

                displayPageResults(num);
            });
        }
```

これでVSCodeで編集していてもbootpagにカーソルを置けば

> (method) JQuery.bootpag(options: JqueryBootpag.Options): JQuery
> jQuery Bootpag plugin main method

と表示されるので、ちゃんと認識できているようです．

### トランスパイル

WebPackを使用．

./node_modules/.bin/webpack

### ところがブラウザで表示させて実行すると

検索結果の表示まではできるのですが、このbootpagで以下のエラーになってしまいます．

TypeError: jquery_1.default(...).bootpag is not a function
at createView (search-es.ts:226)
at search-es-util.ts:37

大本がRequire.jsを使っています．今まで何度も.jsのロードで四苦八苦してきましたので、そのエラーが出ていないということはbootpagの.jsはロードできていると思います．

デバッガで追ってみると、上記のコードの

```js
   total: totalPageNumber, // total pages
```

から

```js
   prev: localization.getLocalization("prev.page")
```

まで実行できて、その先のステップ実行で例外になってしまいます．

解決のヒントがありましたらご教示願います．

［追記］

制御が渡る直前でコンソール出力してみました．

> console.log("$('#wh-search-pagination')=",$('#wh-search-pagination'));

$('#wh-search-pagination')= S.fn.init [div#wh-search-pagination.wh-search-pagination.col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12]

でJQueryはOKです．

console.log("$('#wh-search-pagination').bootpag=",$('#wh-search-pagination').bootpag);

> $('#wh-search-pagination').bootpag= ƒ (t){function s(t,s){s=parseInt(s,10);var r,n=0==i.maxVisible?1:i.maxVisible,d=1==i.maxVisible?0:1,o=Math.floor((s-1)/n)*n,f=t.find("li");i.page=s=0>s?0:s>i.total?i.total:s,f.removeClass(i.activeClass…
> < undefined

でいろいろ出力されますが結局undefinedということなのでしょうか？？

フレームワークに対するプラグインなのでrequireの対象となる.jsはプラグインの中の決まった.jsに記述するのですが、ここに、bootpag.min.jsへのパスを書いても結果は変わりませんでした．

Comment: [TypeError: L.heatLayer is not a function というエラーが、ライブラリのメソッドを呼んだ際に出る](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/28723/typeerror-l-heatlayer-is-not-a-function-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%81%8c-%e3%83%a9%e3%82%a4%e3%83%96%e3%83%a9%e3%83%aa%e3%81%ae%e3%83%a1%e3%82%bd%e3%83%83%e3%83%89%e3%82%92%e5%91%bc%e3%82%93%e3%81%a0%e9%9a%9b%e3%81%ab%e5%87%ba%e3%82%8b?rq=1) が類似と思われますので調べます．

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己RESです．解決しました．

### TypeScript 側の変更事項

以下のコードを記述．

```js
import "bootpag";
```

### webpack.config.js の変更事項

bootpagの記述を追加

```js
    // Excludes dependencies from the output bundles. The created bundle 
    // relies on that dependency to be present in the consumer's environment.
    externals: {
        jquery: 'jquery',
        jqueryui: 'jquery.ui',
        buildparam: 'build-param',
        topicMap: 'topicMap',
        searchHistoryItems: 'searchHistoryItems',
        localization: 'localization',
        util: 'util',
        options: 'options',
        bootpag: 'jquery.bootpag',
    },
```

### フレームワークテンプレートの.jsのrequire指定にbootpagを以下のように追加

```js
define(['require'], function (require) {
    require([
        './suggest',
        './search-es',
        './build-param',
        './topicMap',
        '../../../oxygen-webhelp/app/localization/localization',
        '../../../oxygen-webhelp/app/options/options',
        '../../../oxygen-webhelp/app/options/properties',
        '../../../oxygen-webhelp/lib/jquery-bootpag/jquery.bootpag.min'
    ]);
});
```

お騒がせしました．